# facebook authentication error in release.apk in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created released apk for my android app. I have created the keystore and signed the app with it. Google Plus authentication is working fine but **I am facing problems with facebook authentication.**

I am getting the following message while trying to authenticate app with facebook...

[image]

I have added the provided keyhash to facebook developers' settings. But still I am getting the same error message.

Can anyone tell me how should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Goto to developer settings for your app on facebook and add the Key Hashes shown in the above error manually under settings>basic>Key Hashes. Then try running your app

Answer (score 0):

Try this link [Facebook android app error : Invalid key hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934225/facebook-android-app-error-invalid-key-hash)

I had a similar problem and it turned out that there was an upper case letter I which is similar to lower case letter l, inside this link you will find a code that can get the key hash, use `Log` to show it inside the console and copy paste it, it will do the trick.

Comment: I tried everything but couldn't solve it yet. I added that keyhash to facebook settings and it is in corrected formate. But still same problem.

Comment: did you copy paste the key from the console?