# Facebook login showing error

Tags: android, key, facebook-javascript-sdk

There is a facebook login button  in my android app. I can login using that button. Button  only one time I can login using facebook login button.  I failed to login second time after succesfully logged out.This is the login response I got

> Facebook ErrorInvalid key hash. The key hash HG2kYV1on+6yY1J7stl4KGrNsPA= does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/596405140754842/

But I logged in after copying that hash keys to stored keyhashes in my facebook devolopers page. When I install this app on another phone same problem occured.I solved it by copying that invalid hash key to stored hash keys in my facebook developers page.   I also installed my app on phones without facebook application. In that case a new popup window comes asking email and facebook password. I can login and logout any number of times on those phones

But I need facebook login working on phones with facebook application without coping hash key for every phone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook android app error : Invalid key hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934225/facebook-android-app-error-invalid-key-hash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two keyHashes

1. One using the command prompt:

   ```
   $ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
   ```
2. using the code below:

   ```
   private String getAppKeyHash() {
     try {
       PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
               getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
       for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
           MessageDigest md;

           md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
           md.update(signature.toByteArray());
           String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
           return something;

       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("exception", e.toString());
   }
   return null;
   ```

   }

add both the key Hases in Facebook developers application.

This will work.