# How to solve this facebook key hash error?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

In my project, I am using facebook API for login purpose.
I got key hash error , when ever i try different account or different mobile device. Any body known this type issue. How to solve this. In below, i attached error screenshot.
[image]

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934225/facebook-android-app-error-invalid-key-hash

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674131/android-facebook-integration-invalid-key-hash

Comment: generate the kayhash again and place it in developers.facebook.com

Comment: I already added the Key Hashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void generateHashkey(){
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String s = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                        Base64.NO_WRAP);

                Log.e("HASH KEY ", s);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("Name not found", e.getMessage(), e);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

try to generate the hashkey then copy paste it to developer console facebook.

Comment: where i put this method ?  i put this method to oncreate.

Comment: you can call it in onCreate

Comment: and check log to see the HashKey and the copy that value

Comment: Actually as the error it self says that Invalid HashKey cos it not found in store key hashes so you have to create a hash key and than save it to your developer console

Comment: and the Key that your have save to the developer console and the key which is generated form the apk and checking to the console key did not matched so for that you are getting this error